# Can't access static variables from unit test assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, automapper

I've got a unit test where I'm testing Automapper.

```
var response = mapper.Map<Item>(response);
```

My problem is in my Mapping Profile class, I use a static helper function to map.

```
        .ForMember(destination => destination.Symbol, opts => opts.MapFrom(source => SymbolHelper.GetSymbolPairById(Convert.ToInt32(source.pair))))
```

This function looks like up a static variable which is a Dictionary<T1,T2> which keeps the list of symbols.

`private static IDictionary<string, int> currencyPairs;`

When `SymbolHelper.GetSymbolPairById()` looks up this dictionary, this dictionary is `NULL` and therefore I get a NULL reference exception.

I'm guessing this is NULL because I'm running from a different assembly as my actual application and therefore these variables aren't initialized yet.

So how can I initialize this from a unit test?

Thanks

Comment: *from a different assembly and therefore AppDomain* That doesn't follow at all. Unless you go out of your way, everything runs in the same app domain, regardless of assembly.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Comment: why are you testing automapper? it has it's own tests anyway. Test your own code not a third party application